# how to load packages in apache airflow deployed in kubernetes

Tags: airflow

We have installed airflow using helm chart in our managed eks cluster. some of our dags were working fine, when we introduce one new dag file, we got one error in the airflow UI as follows "from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'". In our local it is working fine. But inside pod we dont have idea what to configure inorder to download the packages automatically and make the code working.

Could anyone please guide in resolving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See extending the Airflow image in the docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/production-guide.html#extending-and-customizing-airflow-image

You need to install your packages into the image then re-deploy.